# How to display a different breadcrumb title for the same controller + action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a `Home` controller and a `Business` controller. The business controller has a few action methods on it: `Search`, `Create`, `Update`, `Delete`.

On my home page I have links to the `Search` and `Create` views on the `Business` controller. The `Search` view also has a link to the `Create` view.

I want the bread crumb to look like the following when `Create` is accessed from the home page:

```
Home > Create
```

…and i want it to look like the following when Create is accessed from the Search page:

```
Home > Business > Create
```

In both the cases the controller/action method is the same, but the breadcrumb I want displayed is different. Is it possible to do this using `MvcSiteMapProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported out of the box. Meaning that you have to adapt the HtmlHelper template to you needs, see https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-functions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done is if you add some information to your route to tell one request apart from the other, then you can configure 2 different nodes to create both breadcrumb trails.

I have a working example of how to do that on my blog: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/10/mvcsitemapprovider-4-seo-features#canonical-tag. Make sure to check out the code download.